How to find the worktree path of a branch
Let's say I'm inside a Git repo with worktrees. Given a branch name, how can I find out if this branch is checked out in a worktree, and if so, the path to this worktree?
P.S. this is for a script, I know I could parse the output of git worktree list, but I'd prefer a solution using git rev-parse or similar.

Not exactly what you're hoping for, but parsing the output of git worktree list --porcelain should be easier and more reliable, since it's intended to be machine readable.

"parsing" it should be as simple as git worktree list --porcelain | grep -B2 "^branch refs/heads/$branchName"

Yeah, didn't realise there was a --porcelain option, that's much better for using in a script.

Based on the hints from commenters joanis and LeGEC:
#!/bin/sh

set -u
branch="$1"
git check-ref-format --branch "$branch" >/dev/null || exit 1
git worktree list --porcelain \
    | grep  "^branch refs/heads/$branch" >/dev/null \
    || exit 1
git worktree list --porcelain \
    | grep -B2 "^branch refs/heads/$branchName" \
    | head -1 | cut -d' ' -f 2

